# Node.js command line tool opens in notepad instead of being executed

Tags: node.js, command-line, npm

I try to create a simple node.js command line tool to get around this concept. I am following this [tutorial](https://developer.atlassian.com/blog/2015/11/scripting-with-node/). Using `npm init`, I have created a project named `lb-model-discovery`. This is the content of the package.json

```
{
  "name": "lb-model-discovery",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "loopback model discovery command line tool",
  "main": "index.js",
  "bin" :{
      "lb-discover":"./index.js"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "seya obey",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

And this is the (very simple) content of the `index.js` at the root of the project:

```
console.log('hello world');
```

After that I executed this command from within the folder (as suggested by the above tutorial):

```
npm install -g
```

This correctly install my tool as a global node command line module. Going into the global repository of node modules in my system (windows), I can see that this is the file created in the npm folder: `lb-discover.cmd`. And here is its content:

```
@"%~dp0\node_modules\lb-model-discovery\index.js"   %*
```

But now when I run my new tool from the command line prompt:

```
$ lb-discover
```

instead of displaying a "Hello world" message in the console, it opens notepad instead and merely display the content of the index.js file.

What am I doing wrong? How can I execute my custom node.js command line?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: try to unlink the file extension .js to be opened with notepad : right click to the file property open with uncheck notepad, i hope this help.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But what do you mean by "unlink" the file extension? Other command line tools in the same folder work just fine

Comment: right click to the file > property > open with > uncheck notepad, i hope this help

Comment: Thanks bit file extension is not the problem since other command line tools with the same extension work just fine

Comment: oh sorry because i known some same situation issue error, but didn't really check your code ;) because isn't posted.

Comment: I was able to fix the problem by modifying the content of the "lb-discover.cmd" (see my answer)

Comment: ;) ok good done, i have to go bed bonne nuit. +10

Answer (score 3):

Add `#!/usr/bin/env node` to the first line of `lb-model-discovery/index.js`. Then install the package again.

This script will be generated

```
@IF EXIST "%~dp0\node.exe" (
  "%~dp0\node.exe"  "%~dp0\node_modules\lb-model-discovery\index.js" %*
) ELSE (
  @SETLOCAL
  @SET PATHEXT=%PATHEXT:;.JS;=;%
  node  "%~dp0\node_modules\lb-model-discovery\index.js" %*
)
```

instead of

```
@"%~dp0\node_modules\lb-model-discovery\index.js"   %*
```

Source: https://blog.npmjs.org/post/118810260230/building-a-simple-command-line-tool-with-npm

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this issue by modifying the content of the `lb-discover.cmd` from this :

```
@"%~dp0\node_modules\lb-model-discovery\index.js"   %*
```

to this:

```
@IF EXIST "%~dp0\node.exe" (
  "%~dp0\node.exe"  "%~dp0\node_modules\lb-model-discovery\index.js" %*
) ELSE (
  @SETLOCAL
  @SET PATHEXT=%PATHEXT:;.JS;=;%
  node  "%~dp0\node_modules\lb-model-discovery\index.js" %*
)
```

My question is why executing `npm install -g` in the first place, generated the wrong script?

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who thinks they've put the `#!/usr/bin/env node` at the start of the script, check again! Some tutorials have an incorrect additional space.

Wrong!: `# !/usr/bin/env node`
Correct: `#!/usr/bin/env node`