# npm install -g generates the wrong script

Tags: command-line, npm

This is a follow up this [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46507320/node-js-command-line-tool-opens-in-notepad-instead-of-being-executed) related to how to install and run a javascript node.js command line tool.

According to this [enter link description here](https://developer.atlassian.com/blog/2015/11/scripting-with-node/) you must execute `npm install -g` from within the folder of your project in order to be installed as a global command line tool executable from prompt.

When I run this instruction a .cmd file is created inside de global npm folder. But its content is wrong:

```
@"%~dp0\node_modules\lb-model-discovery\index.js"   %*
```

I must manually change this content for it to be executed (otherwise I just get notepad being opened...) My question why `npm install -g` does not produced the right script in my system?

Answer (score 0):

The solution is found in this [github issue](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/6674).

Basically the entry script (index.js) must contain this line at the top:

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
```