# npm.cmd opens in notepad instead of being executed (ASP.NET Web API + Angular)

Tags: node.js, asp.net, .net, npm

I have a problem very similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46507320/node-js-command-line-tool-opens-in-notepad-instead-of-being-executed), but instead of a command line application, I have a ASP.NET Web API project with an Angular project inside of it, created using a dotnet template 'angular' (`dotnet new angular --name something`. .NET 6.0.401).

When I run the application with `dotnet run` and open localhost:5097 I get a blank page with a message "Launching the SPA proxy...
This page will automatically redirect to https://localhost:44415 when the SPA proxy is ready." The console constantly prints

```
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaProxy.SpaProxyMiddleware[0]
SPA proxy is not ready. Returning temporary landing page.
```

over and over again.

When I enter localhost:44415 I get an error in the console that says

```
fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaProxy.SpaProxyLaunchManager[0]
Couldn't start the SPA development server with command 'npm start'.
```

and a notepad window is opened with content

```
:: Created by npm, please don't edit manually.
@ECHO OFF

SETLOCAL

SET "NODE_EXE=%~dp0\node.exe"
IF NOT EXIST "%NODE_EXE%" (
  SET "NODE_EXE=node"
)

SET "NPM_CLI_JS=%~dp0\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js"
FOR /F "delims=" %%F IN ('CALL "%NODE_EXE%" "%NPM_CLI_JS%" prefix -g') DO (
  SET "NPM_PREFIX_NPM_CLI_JS=%%F\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js"
)
IF EXIST "%NPM_PREFIX_NPM_CLI_JS%" (
  SET "NPM_CLI_JS=%NPM_PREFIX_NPM_CLI_JS%"
)

"%NODE_EXE%" "%NPM_CLI_JS%" %*
```

which is understandably the same as the npm.cmd's content in my node.js directory. The window name is also "npm.cmd".

As mentioned in the thread I attached previously, I removed a file association for .js in windows settings, but it hasn't changed anything. The last comment there says something about changing the contents of "lb-discover.cmd" file. I don't think an ASP.NET + Angular project has an analogical file to it.

I suspect it might have something to do with file association in windows, but I can't change it for .cmd files.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Found [this](https://www.winhelponline.com/blog/file-association-fixes-windows-10/) link [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1167421/cmd-file-extension-files-are-opening-in-notepad-instead-of-being-executed), might be worth a try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by @Yitz - [this thing](https://www.winhelponline.com/blog/file-association-fixes-windows-10/#google_vignette) worked

Answer (score 0):

Open your .csproj file for editing, find the following property:

```
<SpaProxyLaunchCommand>npm start</SpaProxyLaunchCommand>
```

and change it as follows:

```
<SpaProxyLaunchCommand>cmd.exe /c npm start</SpaProxyLaunchCommand>
```

This should work around possible issues with file association for .cmd